# How do I detect hover to elements inside of each() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thanks for taking a look at my question.

I'm trying to be able to hover over portfolio items but I need to loop through them using each() because I need some way of identifying each item.

I'm trying to hover over **.recent-work-item** to show **.recent-work-item__overlay** the **.show-none** class does **display:none;**

Neither the **hover** nor the **on.("mouseenter", function(){})** is working.

**Here is the HMTL:**

```
<section class="recent-work-item" data-portfolio-id="rwi-<?php echo $i;?>">
<div class="recent-work-item__overlay show-none">
<h3 class="color-white bolder-font"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<a href="#" class="color-red">VIEW CASE</a>
</div>
<div class="recent-work-img">
  <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/img/work1.jpg" class="portrait">
</div>
```

**Here is the jQuery:**

```
$.each($('.recent-work-item'), function(){

var thisid = $(this).attr("data-portfolio-id");
console.log(thisid);

$("[data-portfolio-id="+"'"+thisid+"']").on('mouseenter', function(){
   $(thisid).find('.recent-work-item__overlay').removeClass('show-none');
 });

$("[data-portfolio-id="+"'"+thisid+"']").on('mouseleave',function(){
  $(thisid).find('.recent-work-item__overlay').addClass('show-none');
});

});
```

This is not working, I can't get the hover to work and all I want to do is add or remove a class, can I not do this in each().

I've researched thoroughly in StackOverflow but can't find an answer. I would **REALLY** appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: `$.each($('.recent-work-item')` is wrong

Comment: You could use `:hover` attribute and move the styles of `show-none` to the `recent-work-item__overlay:hover`.

Comment: @brk why is it wrong?

Comment: @NisargShah I'm trying to hover over one element to show another, that wouldn't work.

Comment: That would work. Can you edit your question to show highlight those visible and hidden elements on hover?

Comment: @NisargShah all the class does is display:none; .... I'm trying to remove it on hover to show the overlay.

Comment: I have posted an answer, just to show how you could do this with CSS, instead of javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have test your code in my codepen, and the problem you should use `$(this)` than use `$(thisid)`

```javascript
$.each($('.recent-work-item'), function(){

  var thisid = $(this).attr("data-portfolio-id");

  $("[data-portfolio-id="+"'"+thisid+"']").on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).find('.recent-work-item__overlay').removeClass('show-none');
  });

  $("[data-portfolio-id="+"'"+thisid+"']").on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).find('.recent-work-item__overlay').addClass('show-none');
  });

});
```

Here look at my [codepen](https://codepen.io/A-Geek/pen/MvJbba)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here I have added an example that shows how you could use CSS to show/hide elements. It might not give you exact answer to your problem, but it will help you change your stylesheets as per your requirement.

Essentially, as per the discussion in comments, I don't think you need javascript to design the page the way you need it.

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.container > .hideOnHover {
  display: block;
}

.container > .showOnHover {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover > .hideOnHover {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover > .showOnHover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hideOnHover">
    This text will be hidden on hover.
  </div>
  <div class="showOnHover">
    This text will be shown on hover.
  </div>
</div>
```